Coding in Velo - User input field returning as undefinied
I am attempting to build a calculator in Wix Blocks. I added a text input and set the value to number. When I hit the calculate button nothing happened so I added some code for debugging purposes and the input is returning as undefinied. I have never coded with Velo before so I am very lost as to what the issue is. Any help would be greatly appreciated! TIA!
$w.onReady(function () {
    $w("#calculate").onClick(() => {
        // Fetch the values from input elements
        let soldpriceStr = $w("#soldPrice").value;
        let newhomepriceStr = $w("#newHomePrice").value;
        let downpaymentStr = $w("#downPayment").value;
        let mortgagebalanceStr = $w("#mortgageBalance").value;
        let mortgagepenaltyStr = $w("#mortgagePenalty").value;

        // Log raw values to check what is being retrieved
        console.log("Sold Price (Raw):", soldpriceStr);
        console.log("New Home Price (Raw):", newhomepriceStr);
        console.log("Down Payment (Raw):", downpaymentStr);
        console.log("Mortgage Balance (Raw):", mortgagebalanceStr);
        console.log("Mortgage Penalty (Raw):", mortgagepenaltyStr);

        // Convert values to numbers
        let soldprice = parseFloat(soldpriceStr);
        let newhomeprice = parseFloat(newhomepriceStr);
        let downpayment = parseFloat(downpaymentStr);
        let mortgagebalance = parseFloat(mortgagebalanceStr);
        let mortgagepenalty = parseFloat(mortgagepenaltyStr);

        // Log parsed values to check for NaN
        console.log("Sold Price (Parsed):", soldprice);
        console.log("New Home Price (Parsed):", newhomeprice);
        console.log("Down Payment (Parsed):", downpayment);
        console.log("Mortgage Balance (Parsed):", mortgagebalance);
        console.log("Mortgage Penalty (Parsed):", mortgagepenalty);

        // Check if any value is NaN
        if (isNaN(soldprice) || isNaN(newhomeprice) || isNaN(downpayment) || isNaN(mortgagebalance) || isNaN(mortgagepenalty)) {
            console.error("One or more input values are not numbers. Please check your input fields.");
            return; // Exit the function to prevent further errors
        }

        // Perform calculations
        let listingcommvalue = (soldprice * 0.025);
        let coopcommvalue = (soldprice * 0.025);
        let commhstvalue = ((listingcommvalue + coopcommvalue) * 0.13);
        let lawyerfeevalue = 1800;
        let estproceedsvalue = (soldprice - listingcommvalue - coopcommvalue - commhstvalue - mortgagebalance - mortgagepenalty - lawyerfeevalue);
        let closingcostsvalue = (newhomeprice * 0.025);
        let afterpurchasevalue = (newhomeprice - downpayment - closingcostsvalue);

        // Log calculated values
        console.log("Listing Commission Value:", listingcommvalue);
        console.log("Coop Commission Value:", coopcommvalue);
        console.log("Commission HST Value:", commhstvalue);
        console.log("Lawyer Fee Value:", lawyerfeevalue);
        console.log("Estimated Proceeds Value:", estproceedsvalue);
        console.log("Closing Costs Value:", closingcostsvalue);
        console.log("After Purchase Value:", afterpurchasevalue);

        // Display results
        $w("#listingCommValue").text = listingcommvalue.toFixed(2);
        $w("#coopCommValue").text = coopcommvalue.toFixed(2);
        $w("#commHstValue").text = commhstvalue.toFixed(2);
        $w("#lawyerFeeValue").text = lawyerfeevalue.toFixed(2);
        $w("#estProceedsValue").text = estproceedsvalue.toFixed(2);
        $w("#closingCostsValue").text = closingcostsvalue.toFixed(2);
        $w("#afterPurchaseValue").text = afterpurchasevalue.toFixed(2);
    });
});

I am attempting to have this calculate how much money a user might recieve after selling their home and purchasing a new home. I verified that all text boxes were accepting numbers and the input values were numbers, then I changed it to string just to see whats being returned... undefined.

Indeed you're right that text input always return strings and you need to convert to numbers. That being said, nothing jumps out at me as incorrect here. Is there any other code on the page? Also, this is a lot of code to debug at once. Start by just getting the value from one input element.
